# How to install stop-words package for Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, stop-words

How can I install `stop-words` for Anaconda, which I use for jupyter notebook with Anaconda-Navigator.

I can install with `pip3 install...`, but I need to install with `conda install ...` so I can use the package.

At the end of the day I'd like to be able to do `from stop_words import get_stop_words` in jupyter.

**I've tried:**

`conda install stop-words`

> Solving environment: failed
>
> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
>   current channels:
>
> - stop-words
>
> Current channels:
>
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/osx-64
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/osx-64
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch

There are also "Anaconda" instructions here, https://anaconda.org/pypi/stop-words.

```
To install this package with pip, first run:

anaconda login
and then:
pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/pypi/simple stop-words

Or:

TOKEN=$(anaconda auth --create --name download-token)
and then:
pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/t/$TOKEN/pypi/simple stop-words
```

But this installs with pip, not with conda. So after doing this I still don't have access in jupyter.

Comment: have you install nltk. Do it with:  nltk.download('stopwords')nor on anaconda terminal type: conda install -c anaconda nltk

Answer (score 11):

The solution for me was to use a different package.

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
nltk.download('stopwords')
stopwords = stopwords.words('english')
```

Rather than.

```
from stop_words import get_stop_words
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is given in the [nltk documentation](https://www.nltk.org/data.html):

If you have problems accessing nltk.download in your script, you can install it via the command line interface like
`python -m nltk.downloader all`.

Afterwards the nltk.download command will work like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

`Pip` installer works for `conda` as well, just try

```
 pip install stop-words
```

Answer (score 0):

When installing the NLTK, the directory of nltk has to be C:\nltk_data.

Comment: Hey welcome to StackOverflow I would like you to go through this: [how to give good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

You should simply run the following command:

pipX install stop-words

where X corresponds to the python version installed with Anaconda